# VSCode react native no import errors detected in code

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I have been using vscode for couple of years but recently with version 1.45 i don't see any errors  detected while i code . For example , it does not validate whether the import statement is valid nor the modules inside is valid or not . Earlier it used to clearly mark it in red if a module is not found in the import statement but still declared .

Vscode treats unknown variables as "any" and does not show any error unless i run it in the simulator.

Secondly, whenever i type an object if an import statement is found i used to see the option highlighted and now i don't see that either.

Any clue on why this behavior in vscode?.

Answer (score 4):

install extension "Eslint" and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

For above things, I use some extensions in vscode, It can help you I guess as well,

1. ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets by publisher:"dsznajder"
2. React Native Snippet
   publisher:"Jundat95"
3. EsLint
   publisher:"Dirk Baeumer"

Comment: i have all the 3 extensions you had listed above still it does not show up like how it used to. What i'm trying to figure out is , when you add a component or any component thats written in your class which is not part of any package you had imported,  vscode automatically draws the red line on that specific component indicating its an unidentified object thats not declared or found in any imports.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can use typescript, so that it can easily highlight error.